# What's the best way to communicate PHP settings to Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, xml, settings

**When you are building an application where settings are set serverside with PHP, what's the best way to communicate these settings to Javascript on pageload?**

**Why set all settings serverside and not partly clientside, partly serverside?**
Because the app is certainly in PHP, but the Javascript part may be written in plain Javascript, JS Prototype, jQuery, ...
So this way we remain one set of PHP functions for the whole app independent of the Javascript layer.

I have been thinking of a couple of solutions myself:

**1. Via a hidden form field:**

```
<input typ="hidden" name="settings" value="JSON encoded settings" />
```

Disadvantages:

- Directly viewable in the source code.
- Input hidden is meant to submit hidden data, not to get data.

**2. With Ajax**

As soon as the page loads, there is an ajax post request to the server which retrieves the settings.

Advantages:

- Clean
- Clientside can request only the settings it needs.

Disadvantages:

- Heavier page load

**3. Directly via the source settings file (XML)**

Advantages:

- Javascript and PHP code are completely decoupled (concerning the settings).

Disadvantages:

- Settings file is loaded twice (serverside + clientside)

**4. Something else?**

*Edit: added one advantage for number 2*

Comment: What exactly is wrong with a script tag with variables set according to the settings?

Comment: @DampeS8N Do you mean outputting that script tag serverside?

Comment: if the settings don't come from the user directly, just from a config file, simply echo them into JS that is inside a script tag at the top of your file calls in head. If the data comes from the user, or a (user editable)DB. Don't do that. Like Tybro said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any format like yaml, json, xml, etc. is ok because you can read it with PHP and transform it into  each of the formats.

Maybe the best solutions in your case is a json formatted configuration file. You can read that directly with both JS and PHP when needed.

The Zend Framework has a nice [JSON encoding/decoding component](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.html).

Comment: I will check out the advantages for JSON over XML. Currently the app's config is in XML (the backend admin also loads in the settings from the XML file).

Comment: I have been checking in this out with a couple of sites. Some are using this method. For example www.me.com to load the contacts (but this is secure since you need to log in first) – DADU 3 hours ago

Answer (score 2):

php can generate javascript you know...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var my_var = '<?php $my_var ?>';
</script>
```

Comment: Please read "Why set all settings serverside and not partly clientside, partly serverside?" in the question.

Comment: Just don't do this with things that came from the user. Or $my_var might end up looking like "'; alert('you pwned'); my_var = 'haha"

Comment: DADU: you can use these JS vars anywhere. jQuery, Prototype, so on. They will be global in scope and always exist as long as they are at the top.

Comment: @DampeS8N That's true. Best way would be to make one var appname_settings to prevent naming conflicts.

Comment: yep. Just be extra careful where the data comes from.

Comment: a major flaw here is that web user can see settings you perhaps didn't want him to know of.

Comment: @Vladimir Kocjancic How would you do something in Javascript with certain settings without the web user seeing it?

Comment: We had one app where this was needed. We used ASP.NET, but principle is the same. Your Javascript issues AJAX request to obtain settings in JSON format. Sure, user can still see them with Firebug, as you cannot prevent that. But at least you limit access to the data. It could be security to obscurity though.

Comment: @Vladimir Kocjancic - obviously you wouldn't echo $my_var into your html source if it was something sensitive... but all javascript is client side so it's assumed you wouldn't do that

Comment: @tybro0103 As I said, it only makes getting to data a bit more complex. It doesn't mean that it is safe.